# Pandas While loop through rows until criteria is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, while-loop

I have a dataframe that represents a scatter plot. The goal is to limit the change in slope between points to no more than 0.5 degrees.

```
def calc_slope(frame):
    frame['slope'] = (frame['y'].shift(1)) - frame['y'])  / (frame['x'].shift(1) - frame['x'])
    frame['slope-change'] = frame['slope'] - frame['slope'].shift(-1)
    frame['check-slope'] = ['FAIL' if abs(x) > 0.5 else 'OK' for x in frame['slope-change']]

data = [[1,10.1],[2,10],[3,9.5],[4,9.4],[5,9.3],[6,9.1],[7,8.5],[8,9.4],[9,10],[10,8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x','y'])
calc_slope(df)
```

Now the problem I have is that the I need to increase the y values at point number 7 and 10 in increments of 0.1 until they pass the check, I believe I need a while loop to accomplish this. Here my current attempt which is not working.

```
while  df.loc[df['check-slope'] == "FAIL"]:
    if row['check-slope'] == "FAIL" and row['slope-change'] < 0:
        row['y'] += 0.1
    elif row['check-slope'] == "FAIL" and row['slope-change'] > 0:
        row[idx+1] += 0.1
    calc_slope(df)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear what you are testing in your while loop because you talk about points 7 and 10 but never reference those particular rows and you have slop-change condition that's not discussed either???

this loop does some checks on those rows that contain points 7 and 10 specifically and breaks when both conditions are OK

```
while True:  
    if df.at[6, 'check-slope'] == 'FAIL' or df.at[9, 'check-slope'] == 'FAIL' :
        if df.at[6, 'check-slope'] == 'FAIL' and df.at[6, 'slope-change'] < 0:
            df.at[6, 'y'] += 0.1
        elif df.at[9, 'check-slope'] == 'FAIL' and df.at[9, 'slope-change'] > 0:
            df.at[9, 'y'] += 0.1
        calc_slope(df)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. After running the first part of the code:

Comment: Thanks for your response. After running the first part of the code the only points in the example that Fail are points 7 and 9, however when the change in slope is a positive number the following point needs to be raised, when the change in slope is negative then the y-value in that row needs to be increased. So my goal is to run a while look, while there is a "Fail" in the check column the appropriate y-values are modified until all points "Pass". Thanks for the guidance, I will see if I can modify the code you supplied to accomplish this.